# Do hidden fields always submit the first value from a list of items?

Tags: javascript, java, html, http, servlets

I've been trying to solve this for a long time. Not sure where I'm going wrong. 
I display a list of websites from the database, where each of these URLs have unique IDs (I'm saving these as hidden fields).

```
for(int i = 0; i < favoriteList.length; i++) {  

        String url = favoriteList[i].getUrl();
        out.println("<tr>");
        out.println("<td>");

        out.println(" <form id=\"countForm\"  method=\"POST\">");
        out.println(" <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"favoriteID\" value=\""
                        + favoriteList[i].getFavoriteId() + "\" />");
        out.println("<a" 
            + " href =\" javascript:document.countForm.submit();\""
        + "  onclick=\"document.getElementById('countForm').submit();\"" + " />" + url + "</a>");       
        out.println("</form>");

        out.println("</td> <tr> <td>");
        out.println("<p>" + favoriteList[i].getComment() + "</p>" );
        out.println("</td></tr> <tr><td>");
        out.println("<p>" + favoriteList[i].getClickCount() + "</p>");
        out.println("</td></tr>");
    }
```

The list of websites are displayed correctly. However, after clicking a URL, the form should get submitted and the URL's count should get incremented (basically, trying to count the number of clicks). Whenever I try fetching the ID of the URL(from the hidden field) as `String updateAction = request.getParameter("favoriteID");` , the first link's ID (1) is getting read. Not sure if I'm doing it right.

**EDIT:**
 I understand that writing Servlets is a bad idea, but this is for a homework, where I've got to use Servlets, instead of JSP or other alternatives.

Comment: Note that writing servlets like this is a bad idea for anything in the real world. Instead, use separate templates (like JSP or Thymeleaf) and feed a model to then (e.g., your `favoriteList` retrieved from the database).

Comment: After your 4th out statement add this `System.out.println("value: "+favoriteList[i].getFavoriteId());` and check whether values are set correctly. i.e, 0,1,2,3... If not then maybe you are setting same value for FavoriteId.

Comment: @RohitGaikwad, yes, I tested the values by running a for loop. The IDs were unique. As Andreas mentioned, the problem was with all the forms (for each of the links) having the same ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `favoriteList` has more than one element, then you're creating *multiple* `<form>` elements, all named `countForm`.

`document.getElementById('countForm')` will return the *first*<sup>1</sup> form by that name, so **you're always posting the first form**, not the form with the link in it.

*One way* to fix it, is to name the forms differently, e.g. suffix the form name with the value of `i`:

```
for(int i = 0; i < favoriteList.length; i++) {  

    String url = favoriteList[i].getUrl();
    out.println("<tr>");
    out.println("<td>");

    out.println(" <form id=\"countForm" + i + "\"  method=\"POST\">");
    out.println(" <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"favoriteID\" value=\""
                    + favoriteList[i].getFavoriteId() + "\" />");
    out.println("<a" 
        + " href =\" javascript:document.countForm" + i + ".submit();\""
    + "  onclick=\"document.getElementById('countForm" + i + "').submit();\"" + " />" + url + "</a>");       
    out.println("</form>");

    out.println("</td> <tr> <td>");
    out.println("<p>" + favoriteList[i].getComment() + "</p>" );
    out.println("</td></tr> <tr><td>");
    out.println("<p>" + favoriteList[i].getClickCount() + "</p>");
    out.println("</td></tr>");
}
```

<sup>1</sup> *Note:* The fact that you're getting the first form is browser dependent. The [DOM spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-html.html#method-getElementById) says:

> Returns the Element whose `id` is given by elementId. If no such element exists, returns `null`. Behavior is **not defined** if more than one element has this `id`.

Comment: The problem was exactly with the point you mentioned -- the form IDs were not unique, as a result of which the first form was getting submitted. 
Fixed it by having unique IDs for each of the forms. Thank you so much for accurately pointing out the mistake.